# Formatting column names and result in a pivoted SQL Select Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a pivoted SQL query that will bring up a table. But I need to format the dynamic column names and the results.

This is the query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @yearV varchar(max) = '2019'
DECLARE @idclienteV varchar(max) = 1

select @cols = STUFF(
                        (
                            SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([Y].[FechaPpto]) 
                                FROM [dbo].[Ingresos_Ppto] [Y] 
                                WHERE
                                    ([Y].[IdCliente] = @idclienteV) AND (DATEPART(YEAR, [Y].[FechaPpto]) = @yearV)
                            GROUP BY [Y].[FechaPpto]
                            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

set @query = N'DECLARE @year int = ' + @yearV + ' DECLARE @idc int = ' + @idclienteV + '  SELECT Rubro, ' + @cols + N' FROM 
             (
                SELECT [Y].[Rubro], [Y].[Valor], [Y].[FechaPpto]
                FROM [Ingresos_Ppto] [Y]
                WHERE 
                    ([Y].[IdCliente] = @idc)
                    AND
                    (DATEPART(YEAR, [Y].[FechaPpto]) = @year)
            ) X
            PIVOT
            (
                max(Valor)
                FOR FechaPpto in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p'

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

And this is the table that it'll bring:

```
Rubro                      | Jan 1 2019 12:00 AM | Feb 1 2019 12:00 AM | Mar 1 2019 12:00 AM
+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------
Branding                   | 3280937.00          | 4912017.00          | 2404802.00
+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------
Mercadeo y publicidad      | 3372619.00          | 7423175.00          | 8736550.00
+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------
Portal web WP              | 9148489.00          | 9172295.00          | 4643597.00
+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------
Portal web WP + ecommerce  | 3785304.00          | 9140700.00          | 7425106.00
+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------
Renting tecnológico        | 7223406.00          | 7298693.00          | 8768783.00
+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------
```

So I need to change the dates column name and the result, to get this:

```
Rubro                      | Januray 2019        | February 2019       | March 2019
+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------
Branding                   | $3,280,937.00        | $4,912,017.00        | $2,404,802.00
+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------
Mercadeo y publicidad      | $3,372,619.00        | $7,423,175.00        | $8,736,550.00
+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------
Portal web WP              | $9,148,489.00        | $9,172,295.00        | $4,643,597.00
+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------
Portal web WP + ecommerce  | $3,785,304.00        | $9,140,700.00        | $7,425,106.00
+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------
Renting tecnológico        | $7,223,406.00        | $7,298,693.00        | $8,768,783.00
+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------
```

So far this is what I've tried:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @yearV varchar(max) = '2019'
DECLARE @idclienteV varchar(max) = 1

select @cols = STUFF(
                        (
                            SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(FORMAT(dateadd(month, 0, [Y].[FechaPpto]), 'MMM', 'es-co')) 
                                FROM [dbo].[Ingresos_Ppto] [Y] 
                                WHERE
                                    ([Y].[IdCliente] = @idclienteV) AND (DATEPART(YEAR, [Y].[FechaPpto]) = @yearV)
                            GROUP BY FORMAT(dateadd(month, 0, [Y].[FechaPpto]), 'MMM', 'es-co')
                            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

set @query = N'DECLARE @year int = ' + @yearV + ' DECLARE @idc int = ' + @idclienteV + '  SELECT Rubro, ' + @cols + N' FROM 
             (
                SELECT [Y].[Rubro], [Y].[Valor], [Y].[FechaPpto]
                FROM [Ingresos_Ppto] [Y]
                WHERE 
                    ([Y].[IdCliente] = @idc)
                    AND
                    (DATEPART(YEAR, [Y].[FechaPpto]) = @year)
            ) X
            PIVOT
            (
                max(Valor)
                FOR FORMAT(dateadd(month, 0, [Y].[FechaPpto]), 'MMM', 'es-co') in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p'

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

But I'm getting multiple syntax errors.

How can I format that result?

Answer (score 0):

You need to double the single-quotes in your query string:

```
 FOR FORMAT(dateadd(month, 0, [Y].[FechaPpto]), 'MMM', 'es-co') in
```

Needs to be:

```
 FOR FORMAT(dateadd(month, 0, [Y].[FechaPpto]), ''MMM'', ''es-co'') in
```

etc